# jQuery call back set rails user value to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to set a boolean on my user model to true if they've completed my jQuery tour via the plugin 'jQuery Joyride'.

Not too sure how I should go about doing this but this sounds like the best way to disable the tour for users who have already seen it.

```
$('#contentID').joyride({
  'tipLocation': 'bottom',         // 'top' or 'bottom' in relation to parent
  'nubPosition': 'auto',           // override on a per tooltip bases
  'scrollSpeed': 300,              // Page scrolling speed in ms
  'timer': 2000,                   // 0 = off, all other numbers = time(ms) 
  'startTimerOnClick': true,       // true/false to start timer on first click
  'nextButton': true,              // true/false for next button visibility
  'tipAnimation': 'pop',           // 'pop' or 'fade' in each tip
  'pauseAfter': [],                // array of indexes where to pause the tour after
  'tipAnimationFadeSpeed': 300,    // if 'fade'- speed in ms of transition
  'cookieMonster': true,           // true/false for whether cookies are used
  'cookieName': 'JoyRide',         // choose your own cookie name
  'cookieDomain': false,           // set to false or yoursite.com
  'tipContainer': body,            // Where the tip be attached if not inline
  'postRideCallback': $noop,       // a method to call once the tour closes
  'postStepCallback': $noop        // A method to call after each step
});
```

Any help would be brilliant - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an action to your users controller to update the flag will let you mark the tour complete from jQuery joyride.

In your routes.rb add a member to users resource

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :tour_complete
  end
end
```

And using the `post_ride_callback` from joyride you can call the action with

```
post_ride_callback: function() {
  $.post('<%= tour_complete_user_path(current_user) %>');
}
```

Something to think about is creating a table to track actions performed by a user so you could have multiple tours and mark them complete by passing the id in the `POST` request.

**edit October 11, 2015**

Try setting your tour complete action to the following.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def tour_complete
     current_user.update_column(:completed_tour, true)
     respond_to do |f|
       f.html { redirect_to :back }
       f.json { render json: { success: true } }
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just implemented this, and seems to not be working. Is there a way to set a boolean to true or false?

Comment: @Jonathan I've updated my answer to include the implementation  for the tour_complete action. Let me know what happens when you try it out.